# ESP32 AWS IoT transportStatus=-1

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, mqtt, esp32, esp-idf

I'm following the espressif docs for connecting a ESP32 to AWS IoT shadow. I'm using the example [github.com/espressif/esp-aws-iot](https://github.com/espressif/esp-aws-iot/tree/master/examples/thing_shadow/main) for shadow mqtt synchronisation. I set everything in the config but when I run it on the ESP32, I get the following error:

```
--- until here everything runs fine ---
--- mqtt connects to aws and it's success ---
--- and then ---
I coreMQTT: SUBSCRIBE topic $aws/things/MY_DEVICE_NAME/shadow/name/MY_SHADOW_NAME/delete/accepted to broker.
E coreMQTT: A single byte was not read from the transport: transportStatus=-1.
E coreMQTT: Receiving incoming packet length failed. Status=MQTTRecvFailed
E coreMQTT: Exiting process loop due to failure: ErrorStatus=MQTTRecvFailed
E coreMQTT: MQTT_ProcessLoop returned with status = 4.
```

I tried increasing the network buffer for MQTT packets via the config to 4096 but that didn't help. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. Something was messed up with the policy I created for that device. I'm still not 100% sure what exactly was the problem, but when I removed the code that tried to delete the shadow first before the actual shadow operations begin, the example worked fine. I can now pub/sub to my shadow.

**For anyone having the same problem, comment the code from line 691-746 (part for deletion).**

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered exactly the same error twice now while working with the esp-aws-iot library. What I found was both times it was due to errors in my certificates or credentials.

**serial number or 'client identifier'**
The first time, it was the serial number of the device that was wrong. In my code, I pull a serial number from the nvs and it worked fine. However, I recently upgraded my code - now based loosely on the iot-reference-espc3 library. In this library, a default value for the client identifier is (unhelpfully in my opinion) hard coded into the core_mqtt_agent_mamager. And gives exactly this error.

My fix looks like this:

```
/**
 * @brief Device Serial Number 
 */
static char device_sn[20] = { 0 };

...

/* The client identifier is used to uniquely identify this MQTT client to
 * the MQTT broker. In a production device the identifier can be something
 * unique, such as a device serial number. */
xConnectInfo.pClientIdentifier = device_sn; // XXXX Replaced constant
xConnectInfo.clientIdentifierLength = ( uint16_t ) strlen( device_sn );

...

/* write serial num */
void set_device_sn(char *sn)
{
    strcpy(device_sn, sn);
}
```

**certificates**
The second instance of this error occured when I modifed my partition map and had to reflash the certificates afterwards to nvs. I managed to mix up my certificates with older ones. Which obviously did not work. The problem is that it resulted in exactly this error again. Which isn't hugely helpful.

It's a cryptic error messsage. Hopefully, if you have run into it and you search up this post, it will provide you with a useful checklist: certificates, client identifier, probably any other information you provide during the establishment of the mqtt session. And as per the op's fix, errors in the aws policy attached to the certificate may also trip you up.